# How to query Hive from python connecting using Zookeeper?

Tags: hive, database-connection, apache-zookeeper

I can connect to a Hive (or LLAP) database using [pyhive](https://pypi.org/project/PyHive/) and I can query the database fixing the server host. Here is a code example:

```py
from pyhive import hive
host_name = "vrt1553.xxx.net"
port = 10000
connection = hive.Connection(
    host=host_name,
    port=port,
    username=user,
    kerberos_service_name='hive',
    auth='KERBEROS',
)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('show databases')
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

How could I connect using Zookeeper to get a server name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install the [Kazoo](https://pypi.org/project/kazoo/) package to query Zookeeper and find the host and port of your Hive servers:

```py
import random
from kazoo.client import KazooClient
zk = KazooClient(hosts='vrt1554.xxx.net:2181,vrt1552.xxx.net:2181,vrt1558.xxx.net:2181', read_only=True)
zk.start()
servers = [hiveserver2.split(';')[0].split('=')[1].split(':') 
           for hiveserver2 
           in zk.get_children(path='hiveserver2')]
hive_host, hive_port = random.choice(servers)
zk.stop()
print(hive_host, hive_port)
```

Then just pass `hive_host` and `hive_port` to your Connection constructor:

```
        connection = hive.Connection(
            host=hive_host,
            port=hive_port,
            username=user,
            kerberos_service_name="hive",
            auth="KERBEROS",
        )
```

And query as a standard python sql cursor. Here is using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connection)
```